# Macro runs differently when stepped through

Tags: excel, vba

I created a button that opens different sheets and fires their macros. The final macro, however, does not work when ran this way. It runs without error, it just doesn't do anything. If I step through it, it works as intended. What I'm trying to do is delete any cells within the H column that are blank and shift cells to the left.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteCellsWithBlanks()

Dim rng As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = Workbooks("PCHSFR167663.csv").Sheets(1)

'check column G b/c each row will have a reservation number
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = Range("H1:H" & LastRow)

rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

End Sub
```

Thanks and cheers!

Comment: Qualify your `Range` reference!! (Try `Set rng = sht.Range("H1:H" & LastRow)`)

Comment: And it worked. Thank you @YowE3K